# setConnectiontimeout invalid with 404

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

my httpclient `setConnectiontimeout=5000ms`, if uri is valid but path is invalid, establish tcp connection will fail immediately with response code 404，rather than wait 5 seconds, why?

Answer (score 0):

`Setconnectiontimeout` is for establishing TCP connection with host IP. if URI is valid and if connection could be established, this timeout wont apply further.

Server will return 404 immediately, if path invalid, and there is no timeout option.

Comment: so Setconnectiontimeout  is valid when server is existed and can connect, but server busy or net is busy ?

Comment: When you do `setconnectiontimeout(5000)`, you say to your httpclient that "try connect server, if it is connected cool, else try for 5 seconds, now connected? Cool. not connected? Stop trying". So setconnectiontimeout is unused when server is existed and can connect. But when server is busy or net is busy, its used.